# Amount instance in Corda

Tags: java, kotlin, corda

I am trying to create an instance of the 'Amount' in Corda. I pass a long value and an instance of USD to it.

```
val amount = Amount(value, Currency.getInstance("USD"))
```

Where value is 10.

I want the output to be 10 USD but it's being returned as 0.10 USD, which is expected.
 
Also I understand that USD takes two digits to the right of the decimal point. 
But is there a way to arrive at the solution I want?

Note: The type I expect is Amount<Currency>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Amount<Currency> a = new Amount<>(10, new BigDecimal("1"), Currency.getInstance("USD"));
```

> Amount(quantity: Long, displayTokenSize: BigDecimal, token: T)
>
> Amount represents a positive quantity of some token (currency, asset,
> etc.), measured in quantity of the smallest representable units. The
> nominal quantity represented by each individual token is equal to the
> displayTokenSize. The scale property of the displayTokenSize should
> correctly reflect the displayed decimal places and is used when
> rounding conversions from indicative/displayed amounts in BigDecimal
> to Amount occur via the Amount.fromDecimal method.

or

```
Amount.fromDecimal( new BigDecimal("10"), Currency.getInstance("USD"))
```

> fun  fromDecimal(displayQuantity: BigDecimal, token: T,
> rounding: RoundingMode = RoundingMode.FLOOR):
>
> Amount Build an
> Amount from a decimal representation. For example, with an input of
> "12.34 GBP", returns an amount with a quantity of "1234" tokens. The
> function getDisplayTokenSize is used to determine the conversion
> scaling, for example bonds might be in nominal amounts of 100,
> currencies in 0.01 penny units.

https://api-prod.corda.net/api/corda-os/4.8/html/api/kotlin/corda/net.corda.core.contracts/-amount/